# To what extent the badges or reputation are transmitted from one SE site to another?

Tags: support, reputation, badges

I found out that there are badges, e. g. the `Autobiographer` which can be awarded for a site if the condition for it was fulfilled on another SE site.
Every time I join a new SE site, I directly get some reputation because "You've earned a bonus of 100 reputation because we trust you on other sites in the network".
Are there other badges or sources of reputation a user can get on one SE site because he did something on another SE site?

Answer (score 3):

No, only the [association bonus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) has a cross-site effect:

> If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.

The idea is that if you have 200 rep on one site, then you know the basic rules about how the sites work and shouldn't need to get 50rep on the new site to be able to comment, for example.

[Badges](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/badges) are completely separate and are per-site only. You can get the same badge on multiple sites, but you'll need to meet the badge's criteria on each site to do so.